# Cannot send with StartTLS on Postfix

Tags: email, raspbian, postfix-mta, starttls

I setup a mailserver with a couple different tutorials of Postfix and Dovecot. None of them seemed to actually work 100%. I did get it working with IMAP with SSL on 993 and SMTP with StartTLS on 465. However, mxtoolbox said this might be an open relay.

I wanted to get rid of this error so I added in some smtp restrictions. It gets rid of the error, but now I cannot send via mail clients.

It just sits on sending for a long time and then times out. I pulled the restrictions off of a question here, including fixes to the tutorials to get it working before.

Here is the master.cf:

```
#
# Postfix master process configuration file.  For details on the format
# of the file, see the master(5) manual page (command: "man 5 master" or
# on-line: http://www.postfix.org/master.5.html).
#
# Do not forget to execute "postfix reload" after editing this file.
#
# ==========================================================================
# service type  private unpriv  chroot  wakeup  maxproc command + args
#               (yes)   (yes)   (no)    (never) (100)
# ==========================================================================
smtp      inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
#smtp      inet  n       -       y       -       1       postscreen
#smtpd     pass  -       -       y       -       -       smtpd
#dnsblog   unix  -       -       y       -       0       dnsblog
#tlsproxy  unix  -       -       y       -       0       tlsproxy
submission inet n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
#  -o syslog_name=postfix/submission
#  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
#  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
#  -o smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient=no
#  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=$mua_client_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=$mua_helo_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=$mua_sender_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=
#  -o smtpd_relay_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
#  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
465     inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
#  -o syslog_name=postfix/smtps
#  -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
#  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
#  -o smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient=no
#  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=$mua_client_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=$mua_helo_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=$mua_sender_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=
#  -o smtpd_relay_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
#  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
#628       inet  n       -       y       -       -       qmqpd
pickup    unix  n       -       y       60      1       pickup
cleanup   unix  n       -       y       -       0       cleanup
qmgr      unix  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
#qmgr     unix  n       -       n       300     1       oqmgr
tlsmgr    unix  -       -       y       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite   unix  -       -       y       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce    unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
defer     unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
trace     unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
verify    unix  -       -       y       -       1       verify
flush     unix  n       -       y       1000?   0       flush
proxymap  unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp      unix  -       -       y       -       -       smtp
relay     unix  -       -       y       -       -       smtp
#       -o smtp_helo_timeout=5 -o smtp_connect_timeout=5
showq     unix  n       -       y       -       -       showq
error     unix  -       -       y       -       -       error
retry     unix  -       -       y       -       -       error
discard   unix  -       -       y       -       -       discard
local     unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual   unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp      unix  -       -       y       -       -       lmtp
anvil     unix  -       -       y       -       1       anvil
scache    unix  -       -       y       -       1       scache
#
# ====================================================================
# Interfaces to non-Postfix software. Be sure to examine the manual
# pages of the non-Postfix software to find out what options it wants.
#
# Many of the following services use the Postfix pipe(8) delivery
# agent.  See the pipe(8) man page for information about ${recipient}
# and other message envelope options.
# ====================================================================
#
# maildrop. See the Postfix MAILDROP_README file for details.
# Also specify in main.cf: maildrop_destination_recipient_limit=1
#
maildrop  unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=DRhu user=vmail argv=/usr/bin/maildrop -d ${recipient}
#
# ====================================================================
#
# Recent Cyrus versions can use the existing "lmtp" master.cf entry.
#
# Specify in cyrus.conf:
#   lmtp    cmd="lmtpd -a" listen="localhost:lmtp" proto=tcp4
#
# Specify in main.cf one or more of the following:
#  mailbox_transport = lmtp:inet:localhost
#  virtual_transport = lmtp:inet:localhost
#
# ====================================================================
#
# Cyrus 2.1.5 (Amos Gouaux)
# Also specify in main.cf: cyrus_destination_recipient_limit=1
#
#cyrus     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  user=cyrus argv=/cyrus/bin/deliver -e -r ${sender} -m ${extension} 
${user}
#
# ====================================================================
# Old example of delivery via Cyrus.
#
#old-cyrus unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  flags=R user=cyrus argv=/cyrus/bin/deliver -e -m ${extension} ${user}
#
# ====================================================================
#
# See the Postfix UUCP_README file for configuration details.
#
uucp      unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fqhu user=uucp argv=uux -r -n -z -a$sender - $nexthop!rmail 
($recipient)
#
# Other external delivery methods.
#
ifmail    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=F user=ftn argv=/usr/lib/ifmail/ifmail -r $nexthop ($recipient)
bsmtp     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fq. user=bsmtp argv=/usr/lib/bsmtp/bsmtp -t$nexthop -f$sender 
$recipient
scalemail-backend unix  -       n       n       -       2       pipe
  flags=R user=scalemail argv=/usr/lib/scalemail/bin/scalemail-store 
${nexthop} ${user} ${extension}
mailman   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=FR user=list argv=/usr/lib/mailman/bin/postfix-to-mailman.py
  ${nexthop} ${user}
```

This is my main.cf

```
# See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version

# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Raspbian) This is not an open 
relay.
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /root/fullchain.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /root/privkey.pem
smtpd_use_tls = yes
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes

smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes


smtpd_relay_restrictions =
  # subject even authenticated users and trusted networks
  # to the policy check
  check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:10031
  permit_mynetworks
  reject_unknown_sender_domain
  permit_sasl_authenticated
  defer_unauth_destination

smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
  permit_mynetworks
  permit_sasl_authenticated
  # we exclude our networks and SASL authenticated users
  # from all further checks.
  # since I don't know if the policy service is relevant
  # for unauthenticated mail, I commented it out here
  # check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:10031
  warn_if_reject reject_non_fqdn_hostname
  warn_if_reject reject_non_fqdn_sender
  reject_invalid_hostname
  reject_unknown_sender_domain

smtpd_data_restrictions = reject_unauth_pipelining

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

myhostname = mail.smbecker.tk
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = localhost
relayhost =
mynetworks = 0.0.0.0/0 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all

#Handing off local delivery to Dovecot's LMTP, and telling it where to store 
mail
virtual_transport = lmtp:unix:private/dovecot-lmtp

#Virtual domains, users, and aliases
virtual_mailbox_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox- 
domains.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-maps.cf
virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-alias-maps.cf

inet_protocols = ipv4
```

Basically, I want to be able to send and receive mail from anywhere as long as the domain and user exist on the server and authenticate with IMAP SSL on 993 and SMTP StartTLS on 465. The RPI has no firewall setup, but has a hardware firewall to the web only allowing ports 25,993,465. The client I am having an issue with though is a local PC without a firewall in between.

Before I made the changes to main.cf regarding:

```
smtpd_relay_restrictions =
  # subject even authenticated users and trusted networks
  # to the policy check
  check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:10031
  permit_mynetworks
  reject_unknown_sender_domain
  permit_sasl_authenticated
  defer_unauth_destination

smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
  permit_mynetworks
  permit_sasl_authenticated
  # we exclude our networks and SASL authenticated users
  # from all further checks.
  # since I don't know if the policy service is relevant
  # for unauthenticated mail, I commented it out here
  # check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:10031
  warn_if_reject reject_non_fqdn_hostname
  warn_if_reject reject_non_fqdn_sender
  reject_invalid_hostname
  reject_unknown_sender_domain

smtpd_data_restrictions = reject_unauth_pipelining

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.
```

I was able to telnet on port 465. Now, I cannot. The mail log shows:

```
Jan  6 18:54:41 raspberrypi postfix/smtpd[30109]: lost connection after 
CONNECT from unknown[10.100.100.1]
```

Before making changes, it just said:

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
```

With nothing there.

Any one got any ideas on how to fix this?

Then I can start on Roundcube, DKIM, SFP, DMARC, and getting my ISP to create a PTR for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a tls log setting that will help with TLS issues:

http://www.postfix.org/TLS_README.html

Solution was to add:

```
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 2
```

which then showed me where the issue was.

Issue was here:

```
smtpd_relay_restrictions =
  # subject even authenticated users and trusted networks
  # to the policy check
  check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:10031
```

I commented out the:

```
check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:10031
```

Now everything works and mxtoolbox shows it is not an open relay because it rejects their test message.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, deployment of Postfix is a bit sophisticated.
My first Tip: I am using a wonderful set of Tools regarding deploy an open-source mail server called "Zimbra". It will take care of all you need and gives you a web Interface for management and UI.
Btw I can help you to fix your deployment fellow like this.
My second Tip: You may check firewalls, access permission and `/etc/defaults` if everything is fine. Sometimes simple Issue causes the Problem.

Comment: Not really an answer to the question. I'll look into this if I can't get this working. I have to be really close. Also this suite would have to work on a RPI 3B+. Once postfix is working correctly, everything else should be pretty easy.

Comment: Looked it up and arm is not supported. If it was x86 or 64 I would have plenty of other options than citadel (more issues with no support even here) and postfix.